# How to place a view component in center of a cell in table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am having a table layout of five columns and having check boxes at the last column I want to place the check box at the center of the column in the table layout can any one tell me how to place check box in center at table layout column in android.

This is my xml:

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout_manual_mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:shrinkColumns="5">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/After_connection_heading_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#673AB7" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="CHECK ON J14"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1_manual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/TP_15_Sno"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/TP_15_Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Test_Point_15"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"


                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/TP_15_Range"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cb_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#9e9e9e"/>


</shape>
```

Comment: did your problem got resolve?

Comment: sorry for late dude please wait i am checking it @Kinjal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to add your checkbox into another layout like this**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/shp_circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:gravity="center">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:checked="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have changes your code into my way so just add this into your code. its solve your problem.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks Dude it works for me with RelativeLayout you saved me thanks a lot dude @Kinjal